# Using file path of pre saved word vectors with textTinyR (Doc2Vec)

Tags: r, word2vec, doc2vec

I am getting familiarized with a new package in R called textTinyR which helps to create document level embeddings from the word level embeddings. For this it requires a word_vectors.txt saved in the local system/machine. The idea is to run this and use the results for clustering of text mainly for social media. Some aspects of pre-processing have been already taken into consideration before running the Doc2Vec method of this package (including word vector creation - done using text2vec's Glove method).

Following code snippets are used for this task, all computation are done in the designated working directory:

```
write.table(word_vectors, file = "word_vectors.txt", sep = " ", row.names = TRUE, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

doc_vectors <- Doc2Vec$new(token_list = list(tokens3), word_vector_FILE = "word_vectors.txt", print_every_rows = 5000, verbose = FALSE, copy_data = FALSE)
```

However, the last line results in an error:

> Error in reduced_word_vectors(self$word_vector_FILE, private$unq_tok, 
>   :    Expecting a string vector: [type=list; required=STRSXP].

I have tried few more versions of specifying the path in terms of passing the following to word_vector_FILE argument of Doc2Vec method, but they also result in the same error:

1. word_vector_FILE = paste(c('..', '/Doc2Vec/', 'word_vectors.vec'),
2. word_vector_FILE = "word_vectors.txt".

I also saved the word_vector file in the textTinyR folder as seen in its documentation (and has a dummy word_vec.txt file and used the command: PATH = system.file("example_files", "word_vectors.txt", package = "textTinyR") and passed this file path to the Doc2Vec method, but the error persists.

The sample word vector file can be downloaded from the following link:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dfcf7443c2ed8c4e2dfbf0825db46c2520180903100757/43efc66c2259c00419390c54e8bf1c8220180903100757/8ccc94

Can someone share their suggestions on how to ensure that the file is being read correctly? Thanks for your inputs in advance.

Comment: I guess that the error is related to *list(token3)*. However, I think that the subset of the 'word_vector.txt' that you uploaded in the link can not be of much help to resolve this issue. Is the data that you use to build the word vectors publicly available so that someone can come to the *tokens3* object. Moreover, I think it would be better for such a case to open an issue in the [Github repository](https://github.com/mlampros/textTinyR) of the textTinyR package.

Comment: Hi @Hi Iampros, I don't think the error is related to list(token3). The token3 object is created using quanteda package and is coerced to list before passing it to the Doc2Vec method. The word vectors are not publicly available and specific to a certain use case, but I will try to open an issue on Github repository of textTinyR package, soon. Thanks for your inputs.